# getting the entire error stacktrace in nodejs

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

I follow a simple `try … catch` pattern for my SQLite queries

```
try {
    … run query and get result …
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

On error, I get a nice stacktrace like this

```sh
SqliteError: no such column: 
    at getData (/Users/punkish/Projects/zenodeo/bin/facets.js:8:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/punkish/Projects/zenodeo/bin/facets.js:23:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

I've written my own small logging routine so I can embellish the messages with colors (using `chalk`) and some extra info I find helpful, now I have

```
try {
    … run query and get result …
}
catch (error) {
    mylogger(error);
}
```

Except, now I just get the following

```sh
SqliteError: no such column:
```

And no, the `mylogger` is not eating/chopping away the extra bits. I've added the following to it

```
if (typeof error === 'object') {
    log('type: object');
    log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
}
```

and I get

```
type: object
error: SqliteError: no such column:
```

Seems like the stacktrace is streaming, and all of it doesn't go to `mylogger`. In any case, how can I get all of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Winston and I encountered the same issue before. I'm using `.constructor` instead of `instanceOf` to determine the data type which might be the best practice. But my code here might be of some value to you:

```js
winston​.​format​.​printf​(​info​ ​=>​ {
        ​if​ (​info​.​message​.​constructor​ ​===​ ​Object​ ​||​ ​Error​) {
            ​if​ (​info​.​stack​ ​===​ ​undefined​) {
                ​return​ ​`​${​info​.​timestamp​}​ [​${​info​.​label​}​] ​${​info​.​level​}​: ​${​JSON​.​stringify​(​info​.​message​, ​null​, ​1​)​}​`​;
            } ​else​ {
                ​return​ ​`​${​info​.​timestamp​}​ [​${​info​.​label​}​] ​${​info​.​level​}​: ​${​info​.​message​}​ Stack: ​${​info​.​stack​}​`​;
            }
        } ​else​ {
            ​return​ ​`​${​info​.​timestamp​}​ [​${​info​.​label​}​] ​${​info​.​level​}​: ​${​info​.​message​}​`​;
        }

    })
);
```

Comment: your suggestion actually works, thanks! I still don't understand why my way was not working. I mean, why was the error object not printing out fully. Anyway, your way works and I am happy with that.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's because you're using `typeof` which can be unreliable sometimes.